# PHP Broken during updating to php7

Tags: php, debian

Hey I wanted to update to PHP 7, because I need it for my CMS...
And when I type in `apt-get update`, I get this error:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dist
>   s/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dist
>   s/jessie/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/
>   binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/
>   binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used
>   instead.

Hoping for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting these errors because your `PPA` repositories don't provide packages for your distribution Debian jessie

The most probable that it's happening is that the `PPA` is not longer maintained and needs to be removed

So remove these `PPA's` from your apt source list  and use others instead here [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: so i installed banish404 and now I am getting the following after starting banish.`sources backup folder: /etc/apt/sources_20170807-17:17:28
: 3 3
checking PPAs...
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(zenity:5497): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(zenity:5499): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

`and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install higher php version you should use corresponding guide for your system. This one, for example:

https://tecadmin.net/install-php7-on-debian/#

Hope that helps!